# How to convert a matrix and save to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have some data (1003 rows, 4 columns) in format as seen below, and I want to save them in a csv file:

**Current format:**

```
[['likes_count', 'context', 'category', 'object'], ['1', 1, 0, 4], ['0', 1, 0, 4], ['1', 1, 1, 4], ['1', 1, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 1, 1, 4], ['1', 1, 1, 4], ['1', 1, 1, 4], ['1', 1, 1, 1], ['1', 1, 1, 1], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 1], ['1', 1, 2, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 2, 1], ['1', 0, 0, 4], ['1', 0, 2, 1], ['1', 1, 2, 1], ['1', 1, 2, 1], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['13', 0, 1, 4], ['1', 0, 1, 4], ['2', 1, 2, 4], ['1', 1, 2, 4], [...] etc
```

**Desirable CSV fromat:**

```
'likes_count', 'context', 'category', 'object'
['1', 1, 0, 4] 
['1', 1, 0, 4]
['1', 1, 1, 4]
['1', 1, 0, 4]
['1', 0, 0, 4]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and remember that [asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really as simple as:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(my_list)
```

Where `my_list` is your list. I think you could've found this everywhere on the internet/on SO. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366544/list-to-csv-in-python-with-header), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list), etc...

Comment: @SofiaVlachou sure thing, feel free to mark it as answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: When you find duplicates, the correct action is to flag / vote-to-close this question as a duplicate. Please don't answer duplicate questions!